# Using CakePHP's MediaView with MP4 videos on an iPad

Tags: ipad, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to display MP4 videos through Cake's MediaView class. I have it working fine in Chrome & Firefox, the problem is when trying to view the video on an iPad. All I get is the play icon with a line through the middle of it. The video is able to be viewed if you access the URL of the video directly, however I need this layer in between as videos are restricted on who is able to view them.

I Google'd the problem and found that the iPad uses RangeRequests (Not fully sure on how all that works) when displaying video content, and found my way to [this](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/content-delivery-mobile-devices) article. I then implemented my own View class that incorporated the code in Appendix A (Obviously with a few changes made to suit Cake). I also took a look at Cakes source code for the MediaView class and to me it seemed that it already had code to support range requests. However I have had no luck in getting the videos to work.

I am just wondering if there was anything else that might be causing the problem as I realise that the article linked to is over 4 years old now.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What content type are you actually delivering to the users? The iPad, IPhone and iPods [do not support flash](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/). If this is your problem you can do smart request handling and provide HTML5 content to iOS devices. The RequestHandlerComponent class can detect user agents. For mobile browsers you can use the [`RequestHandler->isMobile()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html#RequestHandlerComponent%3a%3aisMobile) method.
For example to check for a iPad you would use:

```
$this->RequestHandler->isMobile('iPad')
```

which should return `true` if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Delivering it through the HTML5 video tag. Although this is not the problem as it does not work when accessing the URL (Not the actual video, but the URL that delivers the video through the MediaView class)

Comment: So the URL does not work for iOS devices only? Are you sure that this is the case and if so what additional information can you provide that you think may be related to the issue?